# error: request for member 'size' in 'arr1', which is of non-class type 'int*'

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include<array>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
    void median_arr(int arr1[],int arr2[],int n1,int n2)
    {
        int n3=n1+n2;
        int arr3[n3];
        int i=0;
        int j=0;
        int k=0;

        while(i<arr1.size()&& j<arr2.size())
        {
            if(arr1[i]<arr2[j])
            {
                arr3[k]=arr1[i];
                i++;
                k++;
            }
            else
            {
                arr3[k]=arr2[j];
                j++;
                k++;
            }
        }
        while(i<arr1.size())
        {
            arr3[k]=arr1[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        while(j<arr2.size())
        {
            arr3[k]=arr2[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }

        int mid=arr3.size()/2;
        double median=0;

        if(arr3.size()%2==1)
        {
            median=arr3[mid];
        }
        else
        {
            median=(arr3[mid]+arr3[mid-1])/2.0;
        }

        cout<<median<<endl;


    }

int main()
{
    int arr1[]={1,2,8,9,7};
    int n1=sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(arr1[0]);
    int arr2[]={5,6,3};
    int n2=sizeof(arr2)/sizeof(arr2[0]);
    median_arr(arr1,arr2,n1,n2);
    return 0;
}
```

I am facing problems with my C++ program in terms of array operations. But I got the error message that I cannot figure out why?

I think I am missing something here

```
 while(i<arr1.size()&& j<arr2.size())
```

So anyone can help to clarify this?

> error: request for member 'size' in 'arr1', which is of non-class type 'int*'

Comment: Which C++ textbook told you this is possible? Ditch is and get [a good one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: C++ arrays do not have a size function. Did you mean to use a vector?

Comment: Be aware that variable length arrays (VLA, `int arr3[n3];`) are *not* valid C++, but only a compiler extension of *some* compilers. You shouldn't be using them if you want to have portable and/or unlimitedly reusable code.

Comment: You absolutely should read about [including `bits/stdc++.h`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) as well...

Comment: As you included `<array>`, which you obviously don't use: You might have wanted `template <size_t N1, size_t N2>median_arr(std::array<int, N1>& arr1, std::array<int, N2>& arr2)` in which case you could have used `size()` on the arrays as well (or again N1 and N2, yielding shorter code)...

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

> So anyone can help to clarify this?
>
> ```
> error: request for member 'size' in 'arr1', which is of non-class type 'int*'
> ```

The member access operator `.` can only be used on class instances. The type of `arr1` is `int*` i.e. "pointer to int". Pointers are not classes. You cannot use the member access operator `.` on pointers. You used the member access operator `.` on a pointer. Hence the quoted error.

You passed the size of the pointed array as in the parameter `n1`.

---

> ```
> int n3=n1+n2;
> int arr3[n3];
> ```

The size of an array variable must be compile time constant in C++. `n3` is not compile time constant. The program is ill-formed.

---

> ```
> int n1=sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(arr1[0]);
> ```

This is unnecessarily complicated. I recommend:

```
auto n1 = std::size(arr1);
```

Comment: Sir i can't fix it. Can you send me the exact solution? @Aconcagua